# Прикрепить кнопку к активити

Tags: java, android

Есть `ScrollView` на нем `RelativeLayout` и на нем необходимое элементы, нужно добавить кнопку так что бы она была всегда внизу `Activity` при любом положении `ScrollView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так разместите кнопку под ScrollView. Поместите их (`ScrollView` и `Button`) на, к примеру, `RelativeLayout` и разместите как необходимо:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Кнопка получается будет в самом низу, т.е ее можно увидеть только промотав весь `scrollview`, а мне надо бы она была над нижней панелью с системными кнопками

Comment: А Вы попробуйте так сделать и она постоянно будет внизу. Проматывать необходимо, если кнопка внутри `ScrollView`